# How to change payment source for paypal mass payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using paypal mass payment for my marketplace, but each time I use the payouts API it keeps using my paypal balance as the funding source. The problem my paypal account will never get funded, so it will always be 0.00

Is there a way where I can change the primary funding source as my bank account instead of my paypal funds?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Payout API always uses PayPal balance amount, there is no facility for changing the funding source to a bank account. This is an expected behavior.